# Are coefficients and values for x in F[x] in the same set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I'm trying to understand the construction of $F[x]$ where $F$ is a field. As far as I understand it now, all coefficients and roots for all polynomials $f(x) \in F[x]$ lies in $F$. But what about the domain for the polynomials? The set $F[x]$ contains polynomials, but as functions when evaluating any polynomial, do we care how $f$ is defined or must it be that $f:F \to F$ for the field F ?

For example, say $F=Q$. A polynomial $f(x) = x^2-2$ that has a root $\sqrt{2}$, is that polynomial excluded from $F[x]$ or is it just that we really don't care about what $f(x)$ evaluates to?

Comment: Technically, $x$ is just some symbol.  It's akin to talking about the expression $2 \pi^2 + 3 \pi - 1$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't exclude $x^2-2$ from $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. You only need the coefficients to be in $\mathbb{Q}$, not the roots.

The polynomials in $F[x]$ are merely symbols. When you start thinking of them as functions, then the question of domain pops up - this is where field extensions play a role (you can enlarge the domain of a polynomial so that it may now have a root in that new domain).

However, until then, treat them as symbols ($F[x]$ is a vector space over $F$, if you will, which basis elements that can be multiplied together)

Comment: Thanks for sorting this out.